# Viewport for mobile development using mobile emulators

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries, viewport

Do mobile emulators such as MITE(http://mite.keynote.com/) recognise viewport?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

Does anyone know any that do recognise viewport?

Thanks Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the Ripple emulator plugin for Google Chrome? As far as I know it recognises viewport.

Note: it only works with a site held on a server (W/X/MAMP or online)

Comment: I thanks for that it sort of works better than what I was using